# Java Swing + class instance overlap

Tags: java, xml, swing, oop

I am newer to Java and still sometimes get lost with OOP. I am creating a Swing GUI that takes a source file (C, C++, Java) and converts it to XML. My button `RunSourceCode` first converts the source to XML then calls a class named `UnitXMLReader` that analyses the XML created.

What I'm finding is that each use of the button remembers attributes from the previous. At first I was creating the instance of `UnitXMLReader` globally but I thought that if I have each use of the button create a new instance it shouldn't remember attributes from the previous. For example the `getDep()` method returns the correct result on the first use but if I then try a second file (requiring a second press of the button) it returns the combination of both files tried. From what I've read it isn't recommended to manually delete instances but my limited OOP experience tells me that it may solve this issue; is there a safe way to do it to prevent instability?

EDIT: `getDep()` is just a simple get method I added to the class `UnitXMLReader`. The value comes from `dependencyListener`, another class, the code I will past below. It was given to me and assured it works which is why I assumed the error was an instance issue.

//--- Run Source Code Button---//

```
JButton btnRunSourceCode = new JButton("Run Source Code");
btnRunSourceCode.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //------Check for loaded file ----//
        UnitXMLReader XMLRead = new UnitXMLReader();
        try{
            if(filePath == null){
                textArea.setText("Please Load a source file (C, C++, Java)");                   
            }
            else{
                try{
                    textArea.setText("Converting Source Code to XML");
                    String workspace = System.getProperty("user.dir");  //Find location of project workspace
                    String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path"); //Location for targetFile.xml to be stored 
                    //create list of commands to be passed to src2srcml executable. Same as command line
                    String[] commands = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "cd " + workspace + " && ./src2srcml --position " + selectedFile.getName() + " -o " + workspace + "/targetFile.xml"};
                    Process src2XML = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands); //Send Commands to command line
                    src2XML.waitFor();
                    }
                catch(Exception exc){/*src2srcml Fail*/}

                //---- Detect Dependencies ---- //
                File target = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/targetFile.xml");
                System.out.println("Target File: " + target.getAbsolutePath());
                if(filePath != null){
                    XMLRead.ChosenFile = target.getAbsolutePath(); //Send targetFile.xml to XMLUnitReader
                    XMLRead.main(null);
                }
                else{
                    textArea.setText("Please Choose a Source File");
                }

                //TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> dependencies = DependencyListener.getDependencies();
                dependencies = XMLRead.getDep();
                textArea.append("\n");
                textArea.append("Dependencies found at line numbers:" + dependencies + "\n");
                textArea.append("<--------------- "+ XMLRead.sendSize()+"X" +XMLRead.sendSize()+"--------------> ");
                textArea.append("\n");
                int [][] dependencyMatrix = XMLRead.getMatrix();
                List<Integer> lineNumberList = XMLRead.getLineNumbersList();

                textArea.append(" ");
                for(Integer tempInt : XMLRead.getLineNumbersList()){
                    textArea.append(" "+tempInt);
                }
                textArea.append("\n");
                for(int i=0; i< XMLRead.sendSize(); i++){
                    if(i < lineNumberList.size()){
                        textArea.append(Integer.toString(lineNumberList.get(i)));
                    }
                    for(int j=0; j< XMLRead.sendSize(); j++){
                        textArea.append(" "+dependencyMatrix[i][j]);
                    }
                    textArea.append("\n");
                }
                textArea.append("");
            }
    }
    catch(Exception badFile){textArea.setText("Could not read XML");}
    }
    });
btnRunSourceCode.setBounds(612, 39, 156, 25);
contentPane.add(btnRunSourceCode);
```

//-----------DependencyListener -------///

```
package listener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public final class DependencyListener {
    private static TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> dependencies = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();

    public static void addDependency(Integer lineNoOfExpression, Integer lineNoOfDeclaration){
        ArrayList<Integer> declarations = dependencies.get(lineNoOfExpression);
        if(declarations == null) {
            declarations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            dependencies.put(lineNoOfExpression, declarations);
        }
        if(!declarations.contains(lineNoOfDeclaration))
            declarations.add(lineNoOfDeclaration);
    }

    public static TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> getDependencies() {
        return dependencies;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, since you show no code for `getDep()`, I don't see how we could say if there's anything wrong.  I do note it's a static method though, so that might be affect why it "remembers" things.

Comment: You can always force your fields to "unremember" things by initializing them. Create a method called init(), toss all your fields in there and reset them to default values after a button click.

Comment: I am not sure about this but maybe try `XMLRead.ChosenFile = null` after the `catch` block and before you close the `listener`?